# OS X doesn't open dock without clicking when moving mouse to the edge

Tags: macos, dock

I used to move the mouse to the edge where the dock is and it would open immediately. Now the mouse pointer stays stuck in the current window. I have to click and then the dock opens.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try doing `killall Dock` in terminal.

Comment: What "sidebar" are you talking about?

Comment: The launchbar? The one with all the app icons.

Comment: Oh, you mean [the dock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(OS_X)).

Comment: It's not a _sidebar_. You can place the Dock on the bottom of the screen. I like that placement better, actually.